# Laravel Blade read|detail view get the selected option and not the value of select dropdown

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-blade, crudbooster

I have created a custom controller for my crudbooster adminlte dashboard and its custom view in order to be able to read the data of an existing index record.

Several of the fields are select dropdowns which needs to be populate with the selected option and not the value.

```html
<div class='form-group statuslaboID'>
    <label>Status Laboratory</label>
    <p>{{ $orders_detail->statuslaboID }}</p>
</div>
```

View is returning the value of the selected option and not the option (1 instead of Received) :

```html
Status Laboratory
1
```

Could someone point me in the right direction so that I can display the select option of my select dropdowns in my view ?

Thanks, cheers, Marc

---

Laravel Framework 5.4.36
Web server
Laragon (Apache httpd-2-4-29-win64-VC15, MySQL-5-7-19-win64)
Browser
opera, chrome, firefox
CRUDBooster version
v5.4.18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access value from `relationship_table`, like:

```html
{{ $orders_detail->statuslabo->name }}
```

where `statuslabo` is your related model.